# Malloc char array declared in typedef struct

Tags: c, malloc

I have a char array in typedef struct, which is too big (around 260k)

```
#define LENGTH 260000

typedef struct {
   int longSize;
   char hello[LENGTH ];
} p_msg;
```

I would like to use malloc on this char array which as below:

```
typedef struct {
   int longSize;
   char * hello= malloc(sizeof(char));
} p_msg;
```

But it gave me error:

> ```
> error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token
> ```

How can I malloc the char array?

Comment: If you want the dynamically allocated array to be the same size, you need `malloc(LENGTH)` instead of `malloc(sizeof(char))` (for `LENGTH` `char`s, `sizeof(char)` is always 1), though you can't do it in the type definition like that.

Comment: I will need to make the LENGTH bigger than that

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a function from within a struct definition.  You should instead simply keep your first struct definition with the large string inside, and then do `malloc(sizeof(p_msg))` when you want to create one.

Or you can keep it with the pointer inside, and remember to initialize that pointer with the result of `malloc()` every time you create a struct instance.

If you have a function taking the struct by pointer, you can do this:

```
int extMsg(p_msg *msgBuffer)
{
    msgBuffer->longSize = 12;
    msgBuffer->hello = malloc(12);
    snprintf(msgBuffer->hello, 12, "hello %d", 42);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will pass this typedef struct as a param in a function
    int extMsg( p_msg *msgBuffer);

How can I do malloc(sizeof(p_msg))? I'm very new to C. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pointer types, consider this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int longSize;
    char * hello;
} p_msg;

int main()
{
    p_msg msg;
    //zeroing memory to set the initial values
    memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(p_msg));
    //storing the size of char array
    msg.longSize = 260000;
    //dynamically allocating array using stored value
    msg.hello = (char *)malloc(msg.longSize);

    //using msg struct in some function
    int retVal = someFunc(&msg);


    //free hello array after you don't need it
    free(msg.hello);
    msg.hello = 0;
}
```